# Extracting rows in an Excel worksheet where there are duplicates based on selected columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel worksheet where there are multiple records (rows) and I wish to create a new "tab" (worksheet) by removing the "duplicate, triplicate etc." rows based on checking for identical information in certain fields.  How do I do this?

As an example, assume my worksheet is as follows (with a header row):

```
Paper Title          Author             Initial         Year               Topic
The Art of Excel     Bloggs             J               1998               Software
The Art of Excel     Jones              W               1998               Software
The Art of Excel     Jones              W               1999               Software
The Joy of Word      Lyons              Y               2000               Software
The Joy of Word      Roberts            T               2000               Literature
Data Analysis        Brown              D               1979               Statistics
Data Analysis        Black              R               1979               Statistics
```

The data represents papers where more than one author may be involved.  The task is to extract the first entry of each paper only with the check for uniqueness based on fields "Paper Title", "Year" and "Topic", giving the new worksheet as:

```
Paper Title          Author             Initial         Year               Topic
The Art of Excel     Bloggs             J               1998               Software
The Art of Excel     Jones              W               1999               Software
The Joy of Word      Lyons              Y               2000               Software
The Joy of Word      Roberts            T               2000               Literature
Data Analysis        Brown              D               1979               Statistics
```

Assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: I see my formatting of the sample records has been lost

Comment: Click data, Remove duplicates.

Comment: @Noel Highlight a block of text and use the "Code Sample" formatting tool (`{}`) in the editor to force the formatting to be as entered.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily accomplish this with Data ► Data Tools ► Remove Duplicates but first you need to sort the data on the *Year* column with *Year* as *Largest to smallest*.

Remove Duplicates will always cull the second, third, etc duplicate rows, not the first. If you want to use this command (and you should; it is easily the most efficient method), you will need to sort the data so that the first occurrence is the one that you intend to keep.